SSMS navigating to first character when press enter
     SELECT 1
| <- My cursor when I press enter at '1'
     | <- This is where I want it to be when pressing enter

How to navigate my cursor to the first character when pressing enter?

Open Tools -> Options and change the setting Text Editor -> Transact-SQL -> Tabs -> Indenting to "Block".
